# How to check if a deep array value is present

Tags: php

I want to quickly identify if a key is present in an array, to avoid throwing an error.

For example, I might have an array like this

```
$arr['f']['b']['g'] = array( 'a', 'b', 'c', ) ;
```

Or the array might not have any variables in $arr['f']['b'] at all:

```
$arr['f']['x'] = array() ;
```

How can I avoid repetition in a test when referencing the (perhaps) contents of $arr['f']['b']['g']?

```
if ( isset( $arr['f'] ) &&
     isset( $arr['f']['b'] ) &&
     isset( $arr['f']['b']['g'] ) /* ... yawn */ ) {
  /* blah */
}
```

There must be a terser way to identify whether a given array value I'm referencing exists? It seems far too verbose to have to test for the presence of both the value I seek, and all its ancestry as well. In some circumstances that makes sense, yes, but not all.

By example: it might represent, say, user->session->cart, where I want a way to quickly check whether the *cart* has entries, without having to include a check each for whether the *user* exists, then whether the *session* exists, then whether the *cart* exists, then ...

Edit: I'm not looking for "does an array value with a key name of 'g' exist", as "does an array value with an ancestry of f => b => g exist".

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The following will work as you expect:

```
if(isset($a['a']['b']['c']))
```

If any of those elements are undefined, `isset()` will return false.

Comment: Just to clarify, this also safely tests the existence of `$a`: it returns false if `$a` is not set.

Comment: Wow, was sure for years that this does not work. Lol.

Comment: Is `isset($array[$property])` always better than `array_key_exists($property, $array)` ?

Comment: @dev.mnr.j `isset()` is more performant. And `isset` gives you `false` if the array key exists but the value is `null`.

Answer (score -1):

In the comments of [array_search](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) they have code for multi dimensional search. It might help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

There are over a dozen example code blocks on that page (more, I didn't count), but I can't see which one of them which would provide a solution that would be efficient (either in terms of terseness, or performance).

Will update question to clarify what I'm after. Thanks again!